# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

i have two tables  annonces and category and souscategories between them BelongsTo HasMany relationship, same thing between table annonces and souscategories, when I want to insert the data in annonces it gives me error `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (aswak.annonces, CONSTRAINT annonces_category_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)` .

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Salarie::create($request->all());
        $Annonce = new Annonce($request->all());
        //$Annonce->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $Annonce->save();
        session()->flash('success','Annonce add successfully');
        return redirect('annonces');
    }
```

**2020_05_31_164745_create_category_table.php**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique(); 
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**2020_06_22_152000_create_annonces_table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('annonces', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('souscategory_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('souscategory_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('souscategories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('type')->default(false); 
            $table->text('images');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**2020_06_22_151000_create_souscategories_table.php**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('souscategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('souscategorie')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Post your model/relationship also

Comment: Can you please add the insertion code?

Comment: Check whether the category id you're trying to put is actually exists in categiries table.

Comment: @ItzhakAvraham thx for answer in table category exist id bigIncrements